# Websphere MQ error on V7 Queue manager

Tags: ibm-mq

We upgraded MQ to V7 from V6. after the we are facing this error on executing mq commands.

```
retrieving local queue manager
Could not load program dspmq:
                Dependent module /usr/lib/libmqmcs_r.a(shr.o) could not be loaded.
                The module has an invalid magic number.
```

Referring to IBM site,

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21233269

By no where i specify LIBPATH to /usr/mqm/lib in my AIX machine. But on setting the LIBPATH to "" this issue is resolved.

Could you help me to understand how LIBPATH is set for using MQ Libraries ? Will it be set during installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not mentioned what release of MQ v7 you migrated to. MQ v7.1 installation does not create any symbolic links under /usr directory. This is because from v7.1, MQ started supporting multi version installations. One has to use SETMQENV command setup MQ environment.

Please follow this [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27024340&aid=1).

Edit: My suspicion is that LIBPATH might have been pointing to some incorrect mq libraries.

Comment: Hi Vignesh - Have a look at [Implications of a 64-bit queue manager](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.amqaac.doc/aq10320_.htm) for more details. It explains what happens with `LIBPATH` set and unset for various conditions.